# jQuery append breaks my HTML form (with submit button)

Tags: jquery, html, forms, append

I'm trying to create a form with a submit button via jQuery using append().  So the following:

```
out.append('<form name="input" action="/createuser" method="get">');
out.append('Username: <input type="text" name="user" />');
out.append('<input type="submit" value="Submit" />');
out.append('</form>');
```

However, clicking on submit, nothing happens!

However if I do the following:

```
var s = 
'<form name="input" action="/createuser" method="get">' +
'Username: <input type="text" name="user" />' +
'<input type="submit" value="Submit" />' +
'</form>';

out.html(s);
```

Then the submit button works fine!

I'm happy to use the 2nd method, but would rather know what the problem is here.

Thanks

Comment: [He's right you know](http://jsfiddle.net/5rZE5/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With:

```
out.append('<form name="input" action="/createuser" method="get">');
```

the form DOM element is automatically closed by the browser so everything else is added as new DOM elements but not inside the form.

Here's an alternative method which I like for working with the DOM tree:

```
out.append($('<form/>', {
    name: 'input',
    action: '/createuser',
    method: 'get',
    html:
        $('<span/>', {
            html: 'Username: '
        })
        .after(
            $('<input/>', { type: 'text', name: 'user' })
            .after(
                $('<input/>', { type: 'submit', value: 'Submit' })
            )
        )
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Append works a bit different:

```
// create your element first
var form = $('<form name="input" action="/createuser" method="get"></form>');
// add elements to it
form.append('<form name="input" action="/createuser" method="get">');
form.append('Username: <input type="text" name="user" />');
form.append('<input type="submit" value="Submit" />');
// and only then append it to your html
out.append(form);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. As [Darin Dimitrov said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612746/jquery-append-breaks-my-html-form-with-submit-button/5612758#5612758), elements are auto-closed when appended.

Method chaining makes things quite a bit neater:

```
$('<form name="input" action="/createuser" method="get" />')
    .append('Username: <input type="text" name="user" />')
    .append('<input type="submit" value="Submit" />')
    .appendTo(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

This example work perfectly:

**HTML**

```
<body></body>
```

**Script with JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var form=" ";
    form+='<form>';
    form+='<form name="input" action="/createuser" method="get">';
    form+='Username:<input type="text" name="user" /><br/>';
    form+='<input type="submit" value="Submit" />';
    form+='</form>';
    $("body").append(form);
});
```